# How do I do copying in git?

Tags: git

How do you copy a file or a directory with git, preserving revision history? I can't seem to find a way to do it.

What I'd like to do is to split a project into a library and GUI part (now they are mixed in the same project). So I'd like to copy a whole project, and then remove GUI parts from library project, and library parts from GUI project, but preserving the history of every file. It seems trivial undertaking, but I can't find the copy command in git.

So, how do I copy in git?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Record file copy operation with Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043388/record-file-copy-operation-with-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a handy guide at [GitHub](http://help.github.com/split-a-subpath-into-a-new-repo/) which describes how to split a subpath into a new repository.

So, you could `git mv` the code that you want to split out into it's own directory, and use this method to create a new repository based on that folder, which will keep the history of the files intact.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that I should do split, move instead of copy, split, delete :-)

Comment: That link is now 404.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the $git clone commands to copy things from one place to another. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree)** tool to help with splitting subdirectory into separate project.

Read [git-subtree(1)](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/git-subtree.txt) manpage for details.