# How to add better copy detection to gitk?

Tags: git, shell, copy, sh, gitk

In command line Git, the `show`, `diff` and `log` commands have got an option to `--find-copies-harder`.

Is there a way I can tell (or patch) `gitk` to use this, too? I need this from time to time, and my projects are small enough such that I don't care about the reduced performance.

(I don't want to [craft the history to force copy detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46484848/1389680) any more.)

I noticed that the `--find-copies-harder` [appears within the gitk code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/54e85e7af1ac9e9a92888060d6811ae767fea1bc/gitk-git/gitk#L190), but I don't understand why.
So I have tried the command line `gitk --all --find-copies-harder`, but it didn't work: In a commit with a new file copied from another versioned file, gitk still did not display the fact that this file was copied.

Update: Editing the view by entering `--find-copies-harder` into the field `Additional arguments to git log:` also has no effect: A copied (and slightly modified) file is still not shown as copied, while in the command line `git show --find-copies-harder` it is.

Comment: I'm no gitk expert, but the line you linked to is there to *throw out* the option when gitk is running some internal Git commands. Whether it puts the option back somewhere else, I don't know—but it's probably too late, by that point.

Comment: Hmm. Do you see where these `diffargs` are finally used? I have tried adding `--find-copies-harder` directly to the two invocations of `git log` (lines 415, 563 and 1652), but this did not help.

Comment: I see a `set vdflags($n) $diffargs` at the bottom of `parseviewargs`, but vdflags itself is never used anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The necessary change is:

```sh
diff --git a/gitk-git/gitk b/gitk-git/gitk
index 23d9dd1fe0..a98a115080 100755
--- a/gitk-git/gitk
+++ b/gitk-git/gitk
@@ -7909,7 +7909,7 @@ proc diffcmd {ids flags} {
         if {$log_showroot} {
             lappend flags --root
         }
-        set cmd [concat | git diff-tree -r $flags $ids]
+        set cmd [concat | git diff-tree --find-copies-harder -r $flags $ids]
     }
     return $cmd
 }
```

With this, gitk displays the copy in the second commit of the following test repository

```
git init
echo "a file" > a
git add a
git commit -m "a file"
cp a b
git add b
git commit -m "a copy"
```

as desired:

```
-------------------------------------- b --------------------------------------
similarity index 100%
copy from a
copy to b
```

But note that there might be unintended side effects, since the modified procedure 'diffcmd' is called in several places. I did not systematically test all these code paths.

(I have also [sent a generalized version of this patch to the Git mailing list](https://public-inbox.org/git/b12574f0-3ebc-95c0-9def-555150257e46@posteo.net/).)

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem supported without patching somehow the gitk source code itself.

For example, there was in the Git mailing list a [similar request in Feb. 2020](https://public-inbox.org/git/d972c1f1-c49a-f644-ab1c-6a3e26c43ee3@redhat.com/T/#u)

> As of commit [c1a63459ed73](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c1a63459ed7364bb03e0549c1f042bca469d278f) ("`gitk`: Preserve window dimensions on exit
> when not using ttk themes", 2019-12-15, Git v2.29.0-rc0), `gitk` seems to lack two features that I consider "killer" ones, for reviewing patches (including my own
> patches, of course):
>
> - support for the "`--function-context`" ("`-W`") option,
> - support for the "`-O<orderfile>`" (aka "`diff.orderFile`") setting.
>
> These flags are in fact mentioned in the `gitk` source code, going back to
> historical commit [ee66e089c1d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ee66e089c1d4162765a3cec79fd5406e515b0db1) ("`gitk`: Make updates go faster", 2008-05-09, Git v1.5.6-rc0).
>
> The options are stashed in `vdflags($n)`, and then summarily ignored.
> A comment says, "These request or affect diff output, which we don't
> want", and I don't understand why; I would very much like them, please :)
>
> Could someone please write `gitk` patches for honoring "`diff.orderFile`"
> and "`--function-context`"?

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this answer and awarding the bounty: As the question title says, I explicitly ask for instructions on how to modify/patch gitk. Your answer does not add anything useful to the already existing question comments.

Comment: @RobertPollak No problem. Hopefully, someone will have a more precise answer. Mine is just there to illustrate and confirm this is not supported.